# Ubuntu virtual machine cant connect to the internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet

I'm trying to use Ubuntu in virtual box using a Windows 10 host but I cant connect to the internet.

I've been trying everything I can find on google but nothing is working. I should mention that twice I have been able to connect to the internet on the Ubuntu guest but upon restart with the same settings I can one again not get it to connect.

I'm at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you change the `Attached to` and `Name` in virtual box Network settings ?

Comment: Are you able to ping a certain IP-address, like 8.8.8.8? If so, you're DNS-settings are misconfigured and you will have to set them manually, either through the _/etc/network/interfaces_ file ([guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/))  or through the Network Manager in Ubuntu.

Based on my own experience, this is an issue which usually occurs on freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04+

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite new to all this so I don't really know what the guide you linked is talking about.  I have the network settings in the virtual box set to NAT. I've also tried a bridge connection as a few guides have mentioned on google. After pinging in the guest os I got a time of 18.9ms so im guessing it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a Linux VM that wouldn't connect - the issue was two-fold.  Check your network settings for the VM and ensure that the VM can access the host computer's network adapter.  I prefer setting the network connection to bridged, but you can configure it other ways - just do the homework and make sure that is working.

Second issue was the VM was set to not acquire an IP address from the DHCP, it was static.  It installed that way (not sure why) but I had to change it to DHCP and it was able to get a valid IP and get online.  As another poster commented, you should have a valid IP address for your network.